# Oracle Stored Procedure with Spotfire

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, spotfire

I need a step by step example to create a simple Oracle Stored Procedure and link it to Spotfire and get the prompt values of the data of Procedure in Spotfire and get the output data.

Comment: please review the Spotfire and Oracle help files and do some due diligence. then come back and let us know what you've tried.

Comment: @niko: i have already tried on my own i am not able to do it. I tried to refer other posts and mostly they are either related to Spotfire or Oracle Procs. So i need this info to start up on my work

Comment: in order to get a quality answer, you need to ask a quality question. there are literally thousands of examples for making a stored procedure in Oracle and linking it to Spotfire is covered in its help files. if you have trouble implementing a specific example, please add more detail about your use case.

Comment: @niko: i get what you are saying. can you at least provide the examples or sites so i can follow up. I used up all my options and did my share of searches. with no other way i have asked for help and based on the working i will use it for my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with @niko, since this is an old post I'll help out.

First, if you don't know how to create a procedure in Oracle you should really take come courses on it, and Oracle database structure in general. It isn't something you want to just create at random without understanding the potential implications. But, start here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm

Once you have done that, here are the steps to connect it to your analysis.

- Add a data source: `Tools > Information Designer > Data Sources > New
  (Data Source`

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/api-exchange-gateway/2.2.0/doc/html/GUID-3E01F47C-C6A0-49AB-80D4-2D1A3F600FA3.html

- Add your procedure as a data element by expanding your new Data Source and finding your Stored Procedure. Then Right click and select `Create Procedure`
- Next navigate to where you saved this procedure in your library. Right click on it and select `Create Information Link`. Save this information link
- Lastly, in the professional client, add your information link to your analysis.

There are multiple ways to handle the parameters of your procedure, but one of the easiest ways is to create a document property which will take a user input for your parameter, making your data source an On Demand data source.

If you need help with that, research, and then post a question for any clarification that you need.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks @scsimon. i have already added added a function to spotifre. i am working on getting static prompt values to be displayed from the IL instead of the column value being searched dynamucally. also will research on using document property to be used as on demand data which i think will be very much helpful for my work.

Comment: @direwolf, are you wanting to prompt your users for the parameter values, or have the procedure return data for static / default values?

Comment: Prompting user for info is the default thing.i will explain in detail what i exactly require. When single/multiple selection is selected for the column in prompt it takes some time for the unique values to be acquired from the database.i want to add the unique values for that prompt column to be added as a datatable and link it to the actual information link.so when the prompt happens the list from the datatable in spotfire should be loaded for the column. this will make the prompt action faster instead of retrieving data from db everytime. hope i explained properly and need help to achieve it